# T.A.I.L.S mobile OS

Tags: tails, mobile

I am looking at getting t.a.i.l.s mobile o.s. in the near future and need to know the best smartphone to run tails is? I cannot find any answers online. Any advice would be appreciated. Money is not an issue please dont not put something because its to expensive.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Tails for mobile phones. There are people looking into [porting Tails to the arm platform](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/ARM_platforms/), but these efforts are still in a pretty early phase.

Comment: Oh really :/ i thought there was a tails mobile os on torproject website

Comment: Ok well any suggestions on the best snartphone to run tor on? Im using a samsung galaxy s6 edge+ (sm-g928i) cannot root without bricking it. I paid 1200 for a useless piece of crap. What phone should i get to run Tor through?

Answer (score 1):

Actually they better fix their non-mobile OS first : it's buggy like hell. Android Open Source can be modified to use Tor without much troubles, I think - it has a very good structure and API+conventions to add your own components right to the source and build exactly what you want. IPTables are built-in, so there should be no single problem to "torify" the entire system